# Hibernate's @Filter is getting ignored

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

This is my schema
[image: Schema]

I have many posts that contain title and content columns these have a one to one relationship with the translation keys.
Translation keys have many values (one per language)

I'm trying to use a Hibernate @Filter to get a post from the database with only one language.

The translations keys and translations values entities are mapped in a classic way.
But the translation value is not directly mapped to the post entity (there is no foreign key)

The post entity is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "posts")
@NamedQuery(name = "Post.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Post p")
@FilterDef(name = "langfilter", defaultCondition = "language = :langid", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "langid", type = Integer.class))
public class Post implements Identifiable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer identifier;

    // ID of the TranslationKey
    @Column
    private Integer name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Filter(name = "langfilter")
    @JoinColumn(name = "key", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private List<TranslationValue> nameTranslations;

    // Content column is not mapped for testing

}
```

The code I'm using to test is this:

```
EntityManager entityManagerLocal = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Session session = entityManagerLocal.unwrap(Session.class);
session.enableFilter("langfilter").setParameter("langid", 3);
System.out.println(session.find(Post.class, 1));
System.out.println(entityManagerLocal.find(Post.class, 1));
```

The generated SQL query is:

```
SELECT p1_0.`identifier`,
       p1_0.`name`,
       n1_0.`key`,
       n1_0.`identifier`,
       n1_0.`language`,
       n1_0.`value`
FROM   `posts` p1_0
       LEFT JOIN `translations_values` n1_0
              ON p1_0.`name` = n1_0.`key`
WHERE  p1_0.`identifier` =?
```

As you can see the filter is completely ignored. I expect a condition on the LEFT JOIN with `language = 3`

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus question:
Since the relation will always produce only one result (or none at all) is it possible to map it with a @ManyToOne?

I'm using:
spring-boot-starter 3.0.5 (Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final)

**EDIT**

Translation Value mapping

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "translations_values")
@NamedQuery(name = "TranslationValue.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TranslationValue t")
public class TranslationValue implements Identifiable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(View.class)
    private Integer identifier;

    @Column(name = "key", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer keyIdentifier;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "key")
    private TranslationKey key;

    @Column(name = "language", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer languageIdentifier;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "language")
    private Language language;

    @Column(name = "value")
    @Lob
    private String value;

    // Getters & Setters
    
}
```

Translation Key Mapping

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "translations_keys")
@NamedQuery(name = "TranslationKey.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TranslationKey t")
public class TranslationKey implements Identifiable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "identifier")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer identifier;

    @CriteriaParticipant
    @Column(name = "constraint")
    private Integer metadata;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @BatchSize(size = 1000)
    private List<TranslationValue> values;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: language is 2 character type. Filtering with integer=3 seams to be wrong.

Comment: @Mar-Z sorry the image is wrong language is now an integer, but the problem persist

Comment: Please show the other entity classes. And remove the image if it is wrong.

Comment: @Mar-Z it's all up to date now

Answer (score 0):

Basically `@Filter` and `@FilterDef` feature applies the filter definition to a mapped column of the table mapped by the entity class. Fortunately it also works on assotiation tables, but it needs some modification.

Use `@FilterJoinTable` annotation to specify filters on assotiation(s).

```java
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = "langfilter", parameters = {
        @ParamDef(name = "langid", type = Integer.class)
)}
public class Post implements Identifiable, Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer identifier;

    // ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @FilterJoinTable(name = "langFilter", condition = "language = :langid")
    @JoinColumn(name = "key", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private List<TranslationValue> nameTranslations;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: It does not work: Collection 'Post.nameTranslations' is an association with no join table and may not have a '@FilterJoinTable'

Comment: @Emax my mistake. Because a found an other solution a made another answer instead of editing this one.

Comment: No problem, in fact thanks for trying to answer my question

Comment: This should be fine. Just use the correct name of the attribute language identifier =

Comment: This is really not helpful `@FilterJoinTable` can be used only when `@JoinTable` is used. But I don't need it I'm not joining two table over another one it's not a many to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate using different fetching strategies to retrieve entities.

In this case the important strategeis are *direct fetching* and *entity queries*.

Due to a limitation of `@Filter` feature Hibernate only applies filters to *entity queries*.

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class);
    .enableFilter("langfilter")
    .setParameter("langid", 3);

// Using direct fetching strategy - filter won't apply
var post = entityManager.find(Post.class, 1));
```

To apply filter entity queries strategy should used.

```java
entityManager
    .unwrap(Session.class);
    .enableFilter("langfilter")
    .setParameter("langid", 3);

// Using entity queries strategy - filter will apply
var post = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Post p where id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", 1)
    .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the filter is still ignored

Comment: Maybe they'll revert it back. I saw somebody posted a bug -> https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16835